# Update my IPod help

Tags: software-update

I have iOS 6.1.6 on my iPod touch gen 4 and I want to upgrade it to iOS 8 at the least, can anyone help me? I've checked it but it says it's up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Your 4th generation iPod Touch can't be updated past iOS 6.1.6. See [the list of supported devices for iOS 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_7#Supported_devices):

> **iPod Touch**
>
> - iPod Touch (5th generation)

iOS 8 and 9 are the same story - your iPod Touch likely won't get any more software updates.